# Elasticbeanstalk Deployment Fails

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a docker based environment that is using 1-1 application load balancer in AWS elasticbeanstalk. I am getting the below error message. It seemed to deploy very well before but for unknown reasons the new deploys fail.

```
2019-01-31 18:52:23    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2019-01-31 18:53:03    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2019-01-31 18:53:12    INFO    Successfully pulled node:10.15.0     
2019-01-31 18:57:34    INFO    Successfully built aws_beanstalk/staging-app
2019-01-31 18:57:42    ERROR   Failed to start nginx, abort deployment
2019-01-31 18:57:44    ERROR   [Instance: i-0d4b3811324b90c27] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: nginx: [emerg] no host in upstream ":8080" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-upstream.conf:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Failed to start nginx, abort deployment. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/01flip.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2019-01-31 18:57:45    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2019-01-31 18:57:45    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0d4b3811324b90c27'. Aborting the operation.
2019-01-31 18:57:45    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused of an Uncaught error in my Node js application. Issue is not with Beanstalk.